# How to get the value from an asynchronous function for each element of an array and then use the values got to render in a React jsx component

Tags: reactjs, arrays, asynchronous, async-await, promise

I am trying to display some info that I fetched from an api. I can fetch and display the info as needed, but there is one information that requires another operation to be displayed.

So I get the info for each countries like this:

```
{
    "name": "Belgium",
    "topLevelDomain": [".be"],
    "alpha2Code": "BE",
    "alpha3Code": "BEL",
    "callingCodes": ["32"],
    "capital": "Brussels",
    "altSpellings": [
      "BE",
      "België",
      "Belgie",
      "Belgien",
      "Belgique",
      "Kingdom of Belgium",
      "Koninkrijk België",
      "Royaume de Belgique",
      "Königreich Belgien"
    ],
    "subregion": "Western Europe",
    "region": "Europe",
    "population": 11555997,
    "latlng": [50.83333333, 4],
    "demonym": "Belgian",
    "area": 30528,
    "gini": 27.2,
    "timezones": ["UTC+01:00"],
    "borders": ["FRA", "DEU", "LUX", "NLD"],
    "nativeName": "België",
    "numericCode": "056",
    "flags": {
      "svg": "https://flagcdn.com/be.svg",
      "png": "https://flagcdn.com/w320/be.png"
    },
    "currencies": [
      {
        "code": "EUR",
        "name": "Euro",
        "symbol": "€"
      }
    ],
    "languages": [
      {
        "iso639_1": "nl",
        "iso639_2": "nld",
        "name": "Dutch",
        "nativeName": "Nederlands"
      },
      {
        "iso639_1": "fr",
        "iso639_2": "fra",
        "name": "French",
        "nativeName": "français"
      },
      {
        "iso639_1": "de",
        "iso639_2": "deu",
        "name": "German",
        "nativeName": "Deutsch"
      }
    ],
    "translations": {
      "br": "Belgia",
      "pt": "Bélgica",
      "nl": "België",
      "hr": "Belgija",
      "fa": "بلژیک",
      "de": "Belgien",
      "es": "Bélgica",
      "fr": "Belgique",
      "ja": "ベルギー",
      "it": "Belgio",
      "hu": "Belgium"
    },
    "flag": "https://flagcdn.com/be.svg",
    "regionalBlocs": [
      {
        "acronym": "EU",
        "name": "European Union"
      }
    ],
    "cioc": "BEL",
    "independent": true
  }
```

As can be seen, the value of the bordering countries that i got are only codes, not the name  `"borders": ["FRA", "DEU", "LUX", "NLD"],` so I need to tranform them into country names by calling to fetch the api again and get the name. But calling the api and return the value is an asynchronous function.

This is the api call to a local json file :

```
export async function getCountryByCode(code) {
    const response = await fetch('../data.json');
    const dataObject = await response.json();
    const countries = dataObject.filter( e=> e.alpha3Code==code);
    return countries[0]
}
```

this is how i get the value:

```
export async function loader({ params }) {
  console.log(params.code)
  return getCountryByCode(params.code)
}
```

At first, i simply used `array.map`, but obviously it didnt work:

```
 const borderCountriesElement = (country.borders) ? country.borders.map((border, index) => <button key={index}><Link to={`/${border}`}>{getCountryByCode(params.code)}</Link></button>) : (<span> No adjacent countries</span>);
```

Online they say that I should use `Promise.all`, but the problem is that I cannot access the value when i need to return jsx in the component, which needs to be outside the `.then()` block.

```
  let borderCountries = undefined
  let borderCountriesPromArray = undefined;

  if (country.borders) {
    borderCountriesPromArray = country.borders.map(border => {
      let borderProm = getCountryByCode(border);
      return borderProm
    })
  }

  Promise.all(borderCountriesPromArray).
    then(values =>
    {
      borderCountries = values.map((value)=>{
        return value.name
      })
      console.log(values)
    }
  )
```

I also tried `useEffect()`, but this function in `useEffect()` never got run somehow...

```
  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      try {
        // await async "fetchBooks()" function
        const tempCountries = await getCountryByCode(params.code);
        setBorderCountries(tempCountries);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log('Error occured when fetching books');
      }
    })();
  }, []);

  const borderCountriesElement = borderCountries.map(
    (e)=>{
      return (
        <button>
          <Link to={`/${e.alpha3Code}`}>{e.name}</Link>
        </button>
      )
    }
  )
```

Could someone help me? I am very lost

Comment: Sorry, just for clarity, are you saying you need to wait to get the values for border countries, take those values, and then do another GET api call with those values? 

If that's the case, it's actually a good thing you're using an async function to grab this. You can make async functions in js "wait" for other async functions. If you can give a bit more info on my above question I can try to give you a better answer with a code example, but for now check this out: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises specifically the section on "chaining"

Comment: Yes. That is exactly what I need to achieve. I will take a look at the link you provided. thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alrighty, so here's what I came up with. I haven't been able to test this, but hopefully the logic behind it helps you.

```
export async function getCountryByCode(code) {
    const response = await fetch("../data.json");
    const dataObject = await response.json();
    const countries = dataObject.filter((e) => e.alpha3Code == code);
    return countries[0];
}

export async function getBorderCountries(country) {
    if (!country || !country.borders) {
        return null;
    }

    const borderCountries = await Promise.all(
        country.borders.map(async (border) => {
            const response = await fetch("your_endpoint?query=" + border);
            const data = await response.json();
            return data[0];
        })
    );

    return borderCountries;
}

export async function loader({ params }) {
    const country = await getCountryByCode(params.code);
    const borderCountries = await getBorderCountries(country);
    return { country, borderCountries };
}
```

Try this! In your loader function, the call to getBorderCountries will wait for the previous getCountryByCode API call to finish.

Comment: Thank you so much for this! I couldn't work it out on my own but after reading your sample I understood it now.